# Connecting to ethereum network using web3 fails

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to connect to rinkeby using the following code:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const secrets = require("./secret.json");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  secrets.mnemonic,
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/' + secrets.infura
);
web3 = new Web3(provider);
(async () => {
  console.log(await web3.eth.getAccounts()); //returns undefined
})()
```

Note its very similar to the github examples but it fails with the following error

```
/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:119
            callback(err, property.formatOutput(result));
            ^
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

I've also tried to use ganache but i get a very similar error when i call `web3.eth.getAccounts();`

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli')
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
```

Error:

```
callback is not a function
    at /projects/campaignM/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:119:13
```

Comment: Are you using web3 v1.0? Until a few months ago it was not compatible with HDWalletProvider.

Comment: I think that was the issue !